# How to check list is present in other array list in java script ,with out loops

Tags: javascript

> checking obj2 is already exist in obj1
>
> expected result is true but getting false

```
 var obj1 =[
    {Crane:1,Ladle:1},
    {Crane:1,Ladle:2},
    {Crane:2,Ladle:1},
    {Crane:2,Ladle:2}
    ];
    var obj2={Crane:2,Ladle:2}
                        // checking obj 2 is present in obj1
    if(obj1.includes(obj2))
    {
    console.log(true);
    }
    else
    {
    console.log(false);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deep Compare JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48728515/deep-compare-javascript-function)

Comment: No I am getting wrong result

Comment: What is the best way to check array is already exist in list

Answer (score 2):

```
Please find updated code for above problem::

var obj1 = [
    { name:"string1", value:"this" },
    { name:"string2", value:"this4"},
  { name:"string5", value:"this3"},
  { name:"string12", value:"this98"}
];
 var obj2={name:"string2",value:"this4"}
var foundValue = obj1.filter(obj=>obj.name===obj2.name);

console.log(foundValue);

 if(foundValue.length>0)
    {
    console.log(true);
    }
    else
    {
    console.log(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

```js
var obj1 = [
  { Crane: 1, Ladle: 1 },
  { Crane: 1, Ladle: 2 },
  { Crane: 2, Ladle: 1 },
  { Crane: 2, Ladle: 2 }
];

var obj2 = {Crane:2,Ladle:2}

const isPresent = (arr, obj2) => arr.some(obj => obj.Crane === obj2.Crane && obj.Ladle === obj2.Ladle);

if (isPresent(obj1, obj2)) {
    console.log(true);
} else {
    console.log(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer to your question. For example, take a look at [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects/16788517#16788517)
But in such a simple case as yours (if you have no cycle references, no special objects like Map, etc.) your can simply use `stringify()`

```
const obj1_str = JSON.stringify(obj1)
const obj2_str = JSON.stringify(obj2)
console.log(obj1_str.includes(obj2_str))
```